# Android : AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby

Tags: android, audio, android-2.2-froyo, standby

In my HTC Desire (Froyo) , I  initiated a call from the a android app and when the call ends, my android app gone to standby mode by showing

" AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby " in log cat. when i press the back button, only then i can control my app... how can i prevent calling the standby mode..

Comment: what do you mean by "my android app gone to standby mode" ?

Comment: @ Ravi my phone has gone to standby mode....only after pressing back button ,   i can  perform actions

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047817/android-audiohardware-pcm-playback-is-going-to-standby it sounds like the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then in `onCreate()`:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyTag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

And in `onDestroy()`:

```
if (mWakeLock != null) {
    mWakeLock.release();
    mWakeLock = null;
}
```